# c++ error message ostream does not name a type

Tags: c++, iostream

I use c++ to learn about classes and streams but every time I try I get the **error ostream does not name a type** I use std namespace, include iostream, include header

Uhr.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"uhr.h"

using namespace std;

Uhr::Uhr(int Stunde, int Minute, int Sekunde){
this -> Stunde = Stunde;
this -> Minute = Minute;
this -> Sekunde = Sekunde;
}


void Uhr::setTime(int Stunde, int Minute, int Sekunde)
{
 this -> Stunde = Stunde;
 this -> Minute = Minute;
 this -> Sekunde = Sekunde;
}

void Uhr::setOne()
{
this -> Sekunde=+Sekunde;
}

ostream& Uhr::print(ostream& o)
{
o = "Stunden " << Stunden << " Minuten " << Minuten <<" Sekunden" << Sekunden;
return o:   
}

ostream& operator << (ostream &o,const Uhr& u)
{
 return u.print(o);
}
```

uhr.h

```
#include<iostream>

class Uhr
{
private:
int Stunde;
int Minute;
int Sekunde;

public:
Uhr(int Stunde = 0, int Minute = 0, int Sekunde = 0);
void setTime(int Stunde, int Minute, int Sekunde);
void setOne();
ostream& print(ostream & o);
};

ostream& operator << (ostream &o,const Uhr& u);
```

Error:
uhr.h:14:2: error: ‘ostream’ does not name a type
  ostream& print(ostream & o) const;
  ^
uhr.h:17:2: error: ‘ostream’ does not name a type
  ostream& operator << (ostream &o,const Uhr& u);

Comment: It's `std::ostream`

Comment: @Yousaf Not in the header though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yeah right. missed that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the header file `uhr.h`, change

```
ostream& print(ostream & o);
```

to

```
std::ostream& print(std::ostream & o);
```

Comment: *Include using namespace std; in your header file uhr.h* -- No.  Bad advice.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i agree. Edited my answer.